# Prove logarithmic inequality:

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Prove $${\log_{2016}}^{2016}\sqrt{1+\frac{a_2}{a_1}}\quad+\quad {\log_{2016}}^{2016}\sqrt{1+\frac{a_3}{a_2}}\quad+\quad...\quad+\quad {\log_{2016}}^{2016}\sqrt{1+\frac{a_1}{a_{2016}}}\quad \ge \frac{1}{5+{\log_2}63}$$

(It's 2016th root, not $\log_{2016}$ to the power of 2016! I didn't know how to write 2016th root).

I have a solution, but I don't understand it. It says in the solution that the equation above is equivalent to
$$\log_{2016}\frac{(a_1+a_2)(a_2+a_3)...(a_{2016}+a_1)}{a_1a_2...a_{2016}} \ge \log_{2016}2^{2016}$$

I can get the left side to
$$\frac1{2016}\log_{2016}\frac{(a_1+a_2)(a_2+a_3)...(a_{2016}+a_1)}{a_1a_2...a_{2016}}$$

But I don't know how to get the right side as in the solution. How do I get that result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have that

$$\frac{1}{5+{\log_2}63}=\frac{1}{\log_2 32+{\log_2}63}=\frac1{\log_2 (32\cdot 63)}=\frac1{\log_2 2016}=\log_{2016}2$$

Comment: Oh I see :). After we get this we can prove that the new inequality is true using $A \ge G$. In the solution it says that this inequality is true if and only if $a_1=a_2=...=a_{2016}$. Why is it not true for any value of $a_1, a_2,...,a_{2016}$?

Comment: Could you add your derivation by AM-GM? (I suppose you are referrign to that with $A\ge G$)

Comment: We can rewrite the second equation in my question above as (if we remove $\log_{2016}$): $(a_1+a_2)...(a_{2016}+a_1) \ge 2^{2016} \cdot a_1...a_{2016}$, and this can be easily proven by solving AM-GM for $a_1,a_2$; then for $a_2,a_3$; and so on and then multiplying.

Comment: @Pero Then I think it suffices to recall that equality holds for AM-GM when $a_1=a_2=...=a_{2016}$. Its just a property of AM-GM.

Comment: Yeah that confuses me, because we are working with inequalities, there's no equality anywhere, so it seemed weird that they would state that in the solution. I guess they mentioned it like a special case. I understand now thanks for your answers.

Comment: @Pero You are welcome! Bye